# Install custom firmware for Modem

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, firmware

I have a Netgear DGN1000v3 Modem + Router. I want to flash the in built firmware with one that provides me more control over the device. From what I read around in websites I came to know that flashing an unsupported firmware can brick the router.

I looked into Open source firmwares like OpenWRT, dd-WRT, Tomato. But these firmware do not have my router listed in the list of supported devices. Can I go ahead and try to install it? What are the problems that I can face in case the firmware fails?

Is there any tested firmware for my device?

Comment: *"Can I go ahead and try to install it?"* -- Install what?  Firmware intended for another device?

Comment: @sawdust I was planning on installing dd-wrt

Comment: *"I was planning on installing dd-wrt"* -- Uhh, no; this isn't Windows or Linux for a x86 desktop.  This is firmware for an embedded device.  There are builds and images for each specific device.  IOW there is no one firmware image for all devices.  If your device is not supported, then there is no firmware image for your device.  Installing any other image will surely brick the device.

Answer (score 0):

Just read up on the status, e.g. [OpenWRT](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/netgear/dgn1000b):

> Netgear DGN1000 is currently unsupported!
>
> A little work has been done (2016-05) in getting DGN1000SP variants to boot trunk kernels, but it's not useful yet. See the forum thread for details. This work is resurrection of a neglected device; support for most of the platform was added inbetween Attitude Adjustment and Barrier Breaker, but it fell unmaintained before Barrier Breaker froze.
>
> Even if this effort bears fruit, only the 32/8 (e.g. DGN1000SP) variants stand a chance of being supported. 16/4 variants are too small, and the Attitude Adjustment images that would fit on them have some undiagnosed failures in the flash driver.

So, it needs work to make it support the DGN1000. If you install OpenWRT as it currently is, various things won't work (see forum thread from the link).

I suppose the situation for DD-WRT and Tomato is similar, but I'll leave the googling and reading up to you.

Comment: DD-WRT and Tomato also do not support the router currently. I have verified that. Is there any other firmware that you know of that supports this router? I have already checked open-wrt, dd-wrt and tomato

Comment: Read the reason *why* it's not supported yet: Some drivers need work. If *any* router firmware would support it, you could just port it to the other firmwares. Which means very likely no firmware will do. So someone has to sit down and get his hands dirty.

Comment: @NirmalRaj Software recommendations are out of scope.  However, that assumes a firmware exists, other then the OEM firmware.